# Jackson in Jboss / Resteasy

Tags: jboss, jackson, jboss7.x, resteasy

Is there a clean & easy way to enable Jackson implementation in Jboss - AS 7?

Aiming to work only with Jackson and not with Jettison.

I can see that Jboss has support for both:

> /usr/share/jboss-as/modules/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jettison-provider/main/resteasy-jettison-provider-2.3.2.Final.jar
>
> /usr/share/jboss-as/modules/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jackson-provider/main/resteasy-jackson-provider-2.3.2.Final.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This short tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/integrate-jackson-with-resteasy/) explains how you can configure RESTeasy to use Jackson. You might also want to look at [this article](http://blog.xebia.com/2011/07/12/developing-restful-applications-on-jboss-as-7/) on setting up restful applications on JBoss AS 7.